# Can maximum matching algorithms be used for maximum weight matching?

Tags: algorithms, matching

There are two fast algorithms for maximum matching on general graphs:

- Micali and Vazirani in $O(E\sqrt{V})$.
- Mucha and Sankowski in $O(V^{2.376})$.

Can these be also used for maximum weighted matching on general graphs? Note that Edmonds' Blossom algorithm can be used to solve both problems.

Comment: Have you checked the respective papers? Do they mention anything relevant? We expect you to first attempt to solve your question on your own by looking up the relevant background.

Comment: I have checked and it seems like they don’t solve the weighted problem. However I don’t understand them well enough, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: If they don't claim to solve the weighted problem, then they probably don't solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ran Duan and Seth Pettie survey maximum matching algorithms in their 2014 paper [Linear-Time Approximation for Maximum Weight Matching](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/papers/ApproxMWM-JACM.pdf). In particular, Table III in their paper (page 5) lists algorithms for maximum weight matching in general graphs.

Comment: Great paper thank you! Wow linear time approximation is very impressive.